# attaching ec2 instances created by nested stack with load balancer stack using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, stack, amazon-elb

I have created two web servers using nested stack. Also created separate nested stack for Load balancer. I want to attach the two webservers created with Load balancder. I realy dont have much knowledge on nested stack. It would be great if some one render their help. here is the code used for creating my architecture using nested stack

**code for creating Elastic Load balancer using nested stack**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: AWS CloudFormation Sample Template for creating EC2 instance
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Description: WebServer EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid EC2 instance type.
  KeyName:
    Description: Key pair name
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
    Default: muneeshlab
  AMIid:
    Description: Image ID
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Image::Id'
    Default: ami-00eb20669e0990cb4
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
Resources:
  WebInstanceOne:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: !Ref AMIid
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
Outputs:
  InstanceId:
    Value:
      Ref: WebInstanceOne
    Description: ID of virtual server

**code for Load balancer**

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: AWS CloudFormation Sample Template for creating LoadBalancer
Resources:
  ElasticLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZones: !GetAZs ''
      CrossZone: 'true'
      Listeners:
      - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
        InstancePort: '80'
        Protocol: HTTP
      HealthCheck:
        Target: TCP:80
        HealthyThreshold: '3'
        UnhealthyThreshold: '5'
        Interval: '30'
        Timeout: '5'
      ConnectionDrainingPolicy:
        Enabled: 'true'
        Timeout: '300'  

**code for final nested stack**

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: EC2 instance with functions
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Key pair name
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: muneeshlab
Resources:
  MyWebserverstack1:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
        Parameters:
          KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudstack-buck/cloud_web_server.yaml
        TimeoutInMinutes: '5'
  MyWebserverstack2:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
        Parameters:
          KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudstack-buck/cloud_web_server.yaml
        TimeoutInMinutes: '5'
  ElasticLoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    DependsOn:
      - MyWebserverstack2
      - MyWebserverstack1
    Properties:
        TemplateURL:  https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudstack-buck/LB.yaml
```

**Note:** I am able to create three stack without any issue..The only thing I need is to attach the instances with Load balancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is:

- Output the ELB resource Ref in your load balancer stack
- Change over to using an AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup instead of an AWS::EC2::Instance. You can utilize the min/max/desired to mimic a single instance behavior.
- In your parent stack, pass the output of the load balancer stack as a Parameter to the EC2 stack, e.g.: `LoadBalancerName: !GetAtt 'ElasticLoadBalancer.Outputs.LoadBalancerOutputName'`
- Use a reference to the parameter `LoadBalancerName` for the LoadBalancerNames
  property of your AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup

Comment: thankyou for the reply..it would be great help..if you give the valid template

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi StackOverflow is a site for seeking help for programming-related questions. It is not appropriate to ask other people to write code for you. Please try it yourself and, if you have any specific problems, feel free to ask a question. You'll also learn a lot this way!

Comment: @Dennis I did the same but I struck with following error

**Template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [LoadBalancerName] in the Resources block of the template**

I used the following template [link]https://cloudstack-buck.s3.amazonaws.com/stack.yaml

Comment: In your . `Template for ASG` there is no parameter `LoadBalancerName`. You do pass it in the `final stack`, and you did output it in the load balancer stack, but you forgot to define the parameter in the `ASG stack`.

Comment: @Dennis Thankyou for the respose..I tried best still could not find a way how to define Load balancer name in ASG stack....

Comment: Under `Parameters:` add `LoadBalancerName` as a Parameter

Comment: @Dennis I did the same as you mentioned..yet no luck ..https://cloudstack-buck.s3.amazonaws.com/stack.yaml

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/s4guLx1Y
I've added the LoadBalancerName as a Parameter to the ASG stack.

Comment: @Dennis..Thankyou ..I am able to resolve it ..by making few changes with the code you sent..Thanx a lot